# Template Metaprogramming - Type deduction based on enum

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-meta-programming

I am trying to implement a flexible container (Maybe something close to NumPy arrays).

Consider the following code:

```cpp
enum class SupportedTypes { i32, f32 };

struct X {
  SupportedTypes type_;

  X(SupportedTypes type) : type_{type} {}

  void func() {
    switch (type_) {
      case i32:
        // process data as int.
      case f32:
        // process data as float.

    }
  }
};
```

Question:
Can I use template metaprogramming to eliminate the switch case?

Something like:

```
...

using type = unwrap<type_>::type;
```

Comment: The ability to use a user-defined type as a non-type template parameter is a feature of C++20. So that can't happen in C++17. That's why you see a lot of smuggling of "values" into templates via type template parameters.

Comment: I know. But, is there a way to pass a nested non-type template argument to a class? Something like I mentioned in the last part. **Analogy**: A template class that takes `std::bitset<N>` object as template parameter like `my_class<std::bitset<3>{}>`.

Comment: It sounds like you want `my_class` to take a value template parameter, but only a value of a type which itself must be derived from a specific template. And you don't want the template parameters of that template (in this case, `bitset`) to be provided to your `my_class` separately from the value itself.

Comment: I used `bitset` as an analogy. But yes that's what I want.

Comment: Partial specialization. `template <typename T> struct unwrap; template <u64 N> struct unwrap<string_literal<N> data_type> { /* implementation here */ };`

Comment: `unwrap<type_>::type` isn't going to work though, as `type_` is a `char*` pointer pointing to a string of unknown length, not a `string_literal` and not even an array of `char` with a fixed length. It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve; why would you want to refer to a type as `unwrap<"u8">::type` and not, you know, as `u8`?

Comment: Because `u8` is a type stored as string which can change overtime.

Comment: I have abstracted out the complexities out of my question.

Comment: Are we talking about `std::variant` for keeping all given data types and using `std::visit` to "process" the data which is maybe meant by your sentence "eliminate the switch case?". If so, you are ready :-)

Comment: First, can `std::variant` hold a pointer? Second, do I still need to check what data it is holding? Third, can you show with an example?

Comment: Why you don't read the documentation? Yes, it can hold pointers and `std::visit` checks the currently contained type for you. And no, there is no need to add an example as it is part of the documentation. Hint: If you answer on a comment, please add the person you want to answer with an '@' so the person will be notified!